# In Swift iOS, how to refer back to model objects in a callback handler if the model is a struct?

Tags: ios, swift

In my Swift app, I'm trying to follow a more Protocol-Oriented Programming and Value-Oriented Programming approach, keeping core model objects as structs with a thin layer of managing class objects.

In callbacks and completion handlers, one often needs to refer back to a source model object. e.g. When a video finishes loading, you want to take some action on the model object (a struct) that contains the video.

In these situations, what's the best practice way to get a "reference" back to the model object, if it's a struct? (Assume the managing class contains an Array of model structs.)

- Pass back a primary identifier (a property value) for the struct and search for it?
- Some other way of identifying which struct is the one to use?
- Or is this fighting against OOP too hard, and really the model object should be a class, like we've traditionally done, since it has an "identity"?

Comment: I don't really know, I think it's not straightforward... I prefer the class way. I use structs to hold data, not to be my model. Again, that's only my opinion

Comment: Remember structs are value types, so you can't pass a reference, you can just pass an instance of the struct with specific property values. The big risks with using structs is *staleness*. You need to be very disciplined to ensure that your client objects do not store model objects, but fetch them from the model each time.